# R: Select Top N Items of Every Row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R that records the ranked preferences of customers for a number of different brands. A sample of the data frame looks something like the table below. The actual table is much larger in both dimensions (80,000 x 30 approximately).

The table I have:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| User | Brand_A | Brand_B | Brand_C | Brand_D |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| A    | 1       | NA      | 3       | 2       |
| B    | NA      | NA      | NA      | 1       |
| C    | 3       | 2       | 4       | 1       |
| D    | NA      | 1       | 2       | NA      |
+------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

where 1 indicates the customer ranks the brand as the 'best' and NA indicates that the customer has not ranked the brand. I would like to create a table that selects, for each user, the Top 3 (or Top N) ranked brands and outputs a table that might look like this:

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| User | Ranked1 | Ranked2 | Ranked3 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| A    | Brand_A | Brand_D | Brand_C |
| B    | Brand_D | NA      | NA      |
| C    | Brand_D | Brand_B | Brand_A |
| D    | Brand_B | Brand_C | NA      |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Assume that each customers ranking is exhaustive i.e. if I have only used one brand, that brand is automatically ranked 1.

I have tried using for loops to get the required output, but with no success. I think there is something rather simple that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using `apply`:

```
df2=data.frame(User=df$User,t(apply(df,1,function(x) names(x)[-1][order(x[-1],na.last=NA)][1:3])))
colnames(df2)=c("User",paste0("Ranked",c(1:3)))
```

This returns:

```
User Ranked1 Ranked2 Ranked3
1    A Brand_A Brand_D Brand_C
2    B Brand_D    <NA>    <NA>
3    C Brand_D Brand_B Brand_A
4    D Brand_B Brand_C    <NA>
```

Comment: @MikeH. Cool, I've edited the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to melt your data then recast it. This option using `data.table` would look like:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(melt(data, id.vars = "user"))[, rank := paste0("Ranked",value)][!is.na(value),], user ~ rank, value.var = "variable")

#  user Ranked1 Ranked2 Ranked3 Ranked4
#1    A Brand_A Brand_D Brand_C    <NA>
#2    B Brand_D    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
#3    C Brand_D Brand_B Brand_A Brand_C
#4    D Brand_B Brand_C    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you @MikeH. I installed `data.table` but after running the code, I get a warning message telling me "Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length' ".The code still runs, but my output has some strange output columns: Ranked1.5, Ranked2.5, etc. Conflicting packages perhaps (I also have reshape2 installed)? I am not sure.

Comment: Did you try `data.table::dcast`?

Comment: Yes, I did. But got the same result.

Comment: Is it possible that your data has multiple `Brand`'s with the same rank? Because that would cause it to fail

Comment: You are right @Mike H. The code works when I try it on a smaller subset of the data. The issue appears to be with how my ranking algorithm (prior to this step) deals with ties. Looks as though the algorithm averages out ties, which then created those '0.5' columns. Thank you for persisting! :)

Answer (score 1):

with `tidyverse`...

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = '
User Brand_A Brand_B Brand_C Brand_D
A 1 NA 3 2
B NA NA NA 1
C 3 2 4 1
D NA 1 2 NA
')

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(brand, rank, -User, na.rm = T) %>% 
  filter(rank < 4) %>% 
  spread(rank, brand, sep = '')
```

generates...

```
  User   rank1   rank2   rank3
1    A Brand_A Brand_D Brand_C
2    B Brand_D    <NA>    <NA>
3    C Brand_D Brand_B Brand_A
4    D Brand_B Brand_C    <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you. This implementation seems similar to what might be achieved with `dplyr`? However, I am not sure it answers the question posed in that I would still, after the 'spread' be left with a table that has 'Brands' as column headings as opposed to 'Ranked1', 'Ranked2', 'Ranked3', etc for each user. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: It uses both `dplyr` and `tidyr`, both of which are in `tidyverse`. I added the output to the answer... the columns are not named exactly the same, but the structure is the same as you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. I see your point. Very cool use of `dplyr` and `tidyr` functions